# ruby on rails, nested attributes, take highest attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `degree.rb` that `belongs_to :user` (inside `user.rb` - `has_many :degrees`

Let's say a user has 6 degrees. In the degrees table, there is a column called `degree_type` that holds an `int`. What is the best way to pull all 6 degrees and determine the highest `degree_type` number in existence for that user?

It doesn't matter which entry is highest or even if there are duplicates. I just need to know what highest entry for `degree_type` for a specific user exists.

Any suggs? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use maximum:

```
user.degrees.maximum( :degree_type )
```